# Suspend doesn't work, "gzip stdin: not in gzip format" error, initramfs possible missing firmware

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, suspend, encryption

I'm running Xubuntu 20.04 in dual boot with Windows 10 on a laptop (HP Pavilion 15, unfortunately using the AMD Carrizo platform), and I have run into an issue with suspend not working.

When I run Xubuntu from the USB Live environment it works as expected. When I first installed Xubuntu I didn't enable LUKS encryption as it couldn't be done in the installer when installing alongside Windows. As my memory recalls this install also worked as expected.

I then set up partitions and enabled LUKS manually from the Live environment and installed more or less according to this guide: https://gist.github.com/luispabon/db2c9e5f6cc73bb37812a19a40e137bc

Then things got weird.

When I try to suspend the computer I get a black screen with the following in the top left corner:

```
gzip stdin: not in gzip format
cpio: premature end of archive
Press ENTER to continue.
```

When I run update-initramfs I also get this

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_smc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_smc.bin for module amdgpu
```

Something seems to be missing, but when I run `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` it says that both the R6 and R7 cards are using the amdgpu driver.

I am also told by the Software & Updates utility that I am missing additional drivers for the Intel Wireless 3165 dual band wireless AC card, but wifi is working so I'm not sure what that is about, and it's probably unrelated. NTP also didn't work and required manually installing an additional package. In other words, some things that usually are installed by the install environment seems to be missing for some reason.

What I don't get is why this install has these issues, when the Live environment and the previous unencrypted install don't.

I have a lot of experience with Linux, and Ubuntu Server in particular, but as soon as a GUI is put on top and suspend features come into play I don't really know what to look for.

Any guidance on how to troubleshoot and solve these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved.

I use a Yubikey to unlock LUKS, and as part of that I had enabled the service yubikey-luks-suspend.service to require the Yubikey when waking from suspend.

After disabling this script the system suspends as it should. I'll keep it disabled for now.

The possibly firmware warnings are still there of course, but the system works so I'll ignore it for now.